# How to access variable in subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to access the `new` variable of a after insert trigger in a subquery in mysql. How can I get access to it from a subquery?

Comment: Nobody can answer this question without details.  You need to include your code and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this article [MYSQL: AFTER INSERT TRIGGER](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php)

From that link:

### RESTRICTIONS

- You can not create an AFTER trigger on a view.
- You can not update the NEW values.
- You can not update the OLD values.

and how to access `NEW` from that link, their example was

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER contacts_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON contacts FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   DECLARE vUser varchar(50);

   -- Find username of person performing the INSERT into table
   SELECT USER() INTO vUser;

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO contacts_audit
   ( contact_id,
     deleted_date,
     deleted_by)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.contact_id,
     SYSDATE(),
     vUser );

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```